# Can we set separate retention policy for a specific List item that is already uploaded in SharePoint 2016?

Tags: sharepoint-server

I need to programatically set a separate retention policy for specific files that are already uploaded in a document library in SharePoint 2016 on Prem version.

Is it possible to do so?

Let me know the solution for the above scenario.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's doable. On the library settings you turn your head to "Information management policy setting".

> THERE ARE 4 PLACES WHERE YOU CAN DEFINE RETENTION POLICIES IN
>   SHAREPOINT:
>
> 1. Site Collection
> 2. Content Type
> 3. Document Library
> 4. Folder

Reference: [How to set up retention and deletion policies for files and folders in SharePoint](https://sharepointmaven.com/set-retention-deletion-policies-files-folders-sharepoint/)

Comment: Thanks, I already went through this and how my question differs from this is I have 100 files inside a document library and I need to update only two files out of 100 files inside the library with a different retention policy.

Comment: @SumuduP Then you need to move those document to a different document library, or use a specific content type type to accomplist this effect. (The easiest way is to make a new CT who inherits current document type, and name it Retention Policy B for CT xxx).

Comment: I have been trying with your solution and I have created a new CT and applied the retention policy to it. How do you apply CT only to selected files inside a document library? Normally CT is applied to all the files in the document library.

Comment: @SumuduP You can add more than one CT to a library and that would solve your problem if you assign retention policy CT to document A, B and C and the other CT to document D, E and F.

Comment: ♦  Yes, your solution is working for my scenario. I used a separate content type and applied to the document.